# sound-player library not recognizing PulseAudio devices

Tags: pi-3, audio-playback, pulseaudio

Got a Raspberry pi Model 3b - trying to get the bluetooth speaker to work.

Using pulseaudio --start, before pairing the speaker was the way to success.

aplay works with no parameters just the wav file. devices list is below.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
mmap0
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
```

Also 
    aplay --device=pulse  
also works

Now, I am trying to use the sound-player node library - it takes a number of options:

```
var speakerOptions = {
        filename: soundFile,
        gain: 100,
        debug: true,
        player: "aplay", // "afplay" "aplay" "mpg123" "mpg321"
        device: self.configuration.speak.speakerDeviceId
}
```

but none of the devices above seem to work, no errors on the library call (btw calling library is  tjbotlib library so I assume that should work: 
https://github.com/ibmtjbot/tjbotlib/blob/master/lib/tjbot.js
line 1145 and on)